# como hago que en una petición mysql con where se ejecute solo en el ultimo registro de la tabla

Tags: mysql

tengo esta peticion mysql

```
select A.colum1 from   tabla1 as A, tabla2 as B where A.campo1= B.campo2
```

el objetivo es que compare el ultimo registro de los dos campos, ahora esta comparando pero no el ultimo registro, compara todos los registros del campo. gracias por su tiempo toda ayuda vale mucho para mi, como novato en mysql

Comment: Cómo sabes cuál es el "último registro" de la tabla?. Hay algún id?, fecha de inserción?

Comment: si tienen id Lamak

Comment: y ese `id` es creciente?

Comment: si autoicrement

Comment: Quieres comaparar si el ultimo registro de la tabla A es igual al ultimo registro de la tabla B ?